# How do I start MariaDB on boot on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mariadb

Just installed MariaDB (with homebrew).  Everything looks like it's working, but I can't figure out how to have it automatically startup on boot on my Mac.  I can't find any Mac-specific docs for this.

The installation output says:

```
To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy
support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system
```

I guess I don't know where the right place is.

Comment: What are the contents of `mysql.server`? Does it look like a script, or is it an XML plist?

Comment: It's a shell script.  On linux, I'd expect to put this in the rc dirs or something.  Not sure what the OS X way is (I've been spoiled by fancy packagers).

Comment: The accepted answer below will launch MariaDB on user login, but it will not launch it on boot. I'm still trying to find an on-boot solution myself. Putting the login script in /Library/LaunchDaemons doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With help from Calvin's answer (deleted, I guess?), and [this page](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/building-mariadb-on-mac-os-x-using-homebrew/), these are the steps I used to accomplish this:

```
cp /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/5.5.30/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
```

On next boot, MariaDB was up and running.

Comment: ~/Library/LaunchAgents starts the server on login, not on boot. If you disable automatic login on your machine, the database will not be running. Simply moving the plist from LaunchAgents to /Library/LaunchDeamons does not work. Which brings me back to the original question, can you start `mariadb` on *boot*?

Comment: Ha, you're absolutely right, and now I realize that I actually meant to say "on login" in the first place!  Luckily, I only needed this for dev, and not production.

Answer (score 20):

From `brew info mariadb`

```
To have launchd start mariadb now and restart at login:
  brew services start mariadb
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mysql.server start
```

Just run `brew services start mariadb` on terminal.

Comment: That may not have been there when I originally posted the question.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier Maybe useful for someone searching the same question in the future :D

Comment: returns `Service mariadb already started, use brew services restart mariadb to restart.` on mine, neither `start` or `restart` work. there's no process showing for it. The only consistent way I have is to reinstall `brew upgrade mariadb` it after every reboot!

Answer (score 10):

If you install MariaDB by Homebrew, you can use this to see how to start your mariadb at login.

```
brew info mariadb
```

To have launchd start mariadb at login:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mariadb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Then to load mariadb now:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
```

Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:

```
mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `launchd`. See [`$ man launchd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html).

Additionally, [Nathan wrote a good article](http://nathangrigg.net/2012/07/schedule-jobs-using-launchd/) on `launchd`.

Comment: Is this generic OS X advice, or based on experience with MariaDB?

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier It's a rule of thumb in OSX.