# Mysql preference pane working with mariadb 10 (homebrew install) and OS X 10.10

Tags: mysql, macos, mariadb

I am not sure if this is different on earlier OS X but I would like to share how I got the MySQL Preference Pane to work with MariaDB 10.10 installed with homebrew.

First an excellent guide to creating a startup script on OS X:
[How do I start MariaDB on boot on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461170/how-do-i-start-mariadb-on-boot-on-mac-os-x)

MySQL has a preference pane so you can start/stop MariaDB from System Settings. I installed the MySQL Preference Pane.

But it does not work on a brew install mariadb since the paths are different.

- Download and install the MySQL Preference Pane (included in MySQL Mac OS X dmg file download). Open the preference pane and you will see it complains about missing path etc. Does not work.

If this dir does not exist, create it

```
mkdir /usr/local/mysql
```

Create a symblink to share in this dir.

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.0.15/share share
```

Make a symblink to bin in this dir.

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.0.15/bin bin
```

The paths may be different if you have another married version. I have installed 10.0.5.

Data is located in "/usr/local/var/mysql". I did not add any symblink to the data dir. Seems it works fine. I guess this is standard location and no need to specify it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Just to follow SO guidelines, you may put this information in a Q&A format ([read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved this:

- Download and install the MySQL Preference Pane (included in MySQL Mac OS X dmg file download). Open the preference pane and you will see it complains about missing path etc. Does not work.

If this dir does not exist, create it

```
mkdir /usr/local/mysql
```

Create a symblink to share in this dir.

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.0.15/share share
```

Make a symblink to bin in this dir.

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.0.15/bin bin
```

The paths may be different if you have another mariaDB version. I have installed 10.0.15.

Data is located in "/usr/local/var/mysql". I did not add any symblink to the data dir. Seems it works fine. I guess this is standard location and no need to specify it.